# Lanterna: Page up / Page down

Tags: java, terminal, keyboard, lanterna

Is it possible to capture page up and page down keys using [Lanterna](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/)? I'm creating a (specialized) hex editor in Java and thought that it would be a good idea to integrate terminal / curses support as well. If it isn't possible, is it possible in one of the other libraries that use native code (such as the Java curses library)?

Or should I go the way of `more` and `less` and use specific keys (space and `b` for back)?

Comment: I haven't tried to capture everything yet, I'll try and do that if nobody can answer this. The API does not seem to mention PG UP/PG DOWN anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Key.Kind` in Lanterna 2 and `KeyType` in Lanterna 3 can be used to find these keys. So you should not look for specific characters.

All the function keys, and all the control keys, even including the enter key can be easily found this way. Only the normal letters and other characters are indicated by `NormalKey` in Lanterna 2 and `Character` in Lanterna 3.

For Lanterna 2, this information can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/wiki/UsingTerminal) under caption *Read keyboard input*.